# Ordering MYSQL by date then time

Tags: mysql

I am trying to order MYSQL by date then time.

```
SELECT START_DATE FROM Table ORDER BY DATE(START_DATE) DESC, TIME(START_DATE) ASC
```

so what i am trying to do is to get all entries ordering by latest date then order those entries by earliest time.

Exampe:

```
    2016-11-6 6:45:00
    2016-11-6 6:30:00
    2016-11-6 6:15:00
    2016-11-5 6:30:00 
    2016-11-4 6:30:00
    2016-11-4 6:15:00
```

i want to have the data ordered like the above example but, i then want to have 2016-11-4 6:15:00 on top of 6:30:00. any way to do this?

Comment: You show an SQL query at the top of your question that should do exactly what you ask. Is it not?

Comment: it does not do it. it seems to ignore TIME()

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that in fact... I mean, sort by a sub-part of a field.

Comment: Maybe you just need to quote the table name: http://rextester.com/LRK52502

Comment: It works just fine. Here's a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55e18e/2

Comment: @BillKarwin yes the query worked fine

Comment: @sam Please show your table structure